# exact_extract Coverage area wrong fcoverage fraction

Tags: r, sf, extract, terra

I'm using R to extract the values from a raster into a polygon. It works fine for most of them, but I found this small polygon (which is smaller than the cells) where it is giving me some misleading results. I still cannot find the clue of what's happening.

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(exactextractr)

filter<- st_read("/tmp/filter/filter.shp")
current_SOC <- terra::rast("/tmp/current_soc_june2021_data/Current_SOC30_mean_June2021a.tif")


# https://epsg.io/4283
# https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/crs.html
crs <- "EPSG:4283"
p <- project(current_SOC, crs)

#--- extract values from the raster for the SA2's ---#
tall_by_SA2 <- exact_extract(p, filter)# grid_compat_tol = TRUE) 
(
#--- combine ---#
tall_combined <- bind_rows(tall_by_SA2, .id = "id") %>% 
  as_tibble()
)
```

The result I get is the following:

```
Warning in .local(x, y, ...) :
  Polygons transformed to raster CRS (EPSG:4283)
# A tibble: 14 × 3
   id    value coverage_fraction
   <chr> <dbl>             <dbl>
 1 1      38.8       0.000000358
 2 1      73.8       0.0000202  
 3 1      61.1       0.00000345 
 4 1      61.4       0.00000314 
 5 1      67.8       0.0000154  
 6 1      60.7       0.0000106  
 7 1      62.3       0.00000587 
 8 1      66.2       1.00       
 9 1      73.5       0.00000128 
10 1      64.8       1.00       
11 1      72.5       1.00       
12 1      70.0       1.00       
13 1      66.3       1.00       
14 1      67.8       1.00
```

But I find that result cannot be possible (the polygon is too small to cover completely some of the cells in the grid).

I leave you the polygon file uploaded on the following link https://filedropper.com/d/s/HAaBqZY14T6ELiIeZG2Zq6DHdt467p

The raster file can be downloaded from:

https://datasets.seed.nsw.gov.au/dataset/soil-carbon-sequestration-potential-with-enhanced-vegetation-cover-over-nsw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing incorrect results because your polygon, while valid in its native CRS, becomes invalid when transformed to the CRS of the raster:

```
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
st_is_valid(p)
# [1] TRUE

pp <- st_transform(p, st_crs(r))
st_is_valid(pp)
# [1] FALSE
```

The invalid polygon has self-intersections within some raster cells, causing an incorrect coverage fraction to be calculated. I've ticketed the issue at https://github.com/isciences/exactextract/issues/29

Comment: It's clear. What about the solution I posted below? Would be an incorrect approach to assign to the raster the CRS from the polygon? The results look much more reasonable now, with that small polygon having a small share of each cell.

Comment: I don't think it's incorrect, as long as the interpolation performed by `project` is appropriate for your data.

Answer (score 0):

For any future person, the problem is that my original raster doesn't have any CRS. Where I was giving the raster a projection it wasn't working, so I changed that line for the next one:

```
# Setting a projection to current_SOC
terra::crs(filter)
current_SOC <- project(current_SOC, terra::crs(filter))
```

In this way, the new result gives a fraction of the cells for all the cells that intersect with the polygon.